# index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 0: Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've recently come across an issue when trying to run a for loop on a dataframe where it will seemingly loop through 427,942 rows before it results in the following error: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 0.

Here are the two code blocks I think to be relevant:

```
outcome = []

def get_matchup(team_a_input, team_b_input, season_input):
    team_a = team_a_input
    team_b = team_b_input
    season = season_input

    team_a_stats = df.loc[(df.TeamID == team_a) & (df.Season == season)]
    team_a_results = team_a_stats['Result']
    team_a_stats = team_a_stats.drop(['Result'], axis=1)

    team_b_stats = df.loc[(df.TeamID == team_b) & (df.Season == season)]
    team_b_results = team_b_stats['Result']
    team_b_stats = team_b_stats.drop(['Result'], axis=1)

    probs_team_a = loaded_model.predict_proba(team_a_stats)
    probs_team_a = probs_team_a[:,1]
    loss_team_a = brier_score_loss(team_a_results, probs_team_a)

    probs_team_b = loaded_model.predict_proba(team_b_stats)
    probs_team_b = probs_team_b[:,1]
    loss_team_b = brier_score_loss(team_b_results, probs_team_b)
    
    team_a_win_prob = probs_team_a.mean()/(probs_team_a.mean()+probs_team_b.mean())
    team_b_win_prob = probs_team_b.mean()/(probs_team_a.mean()+probs_team_b.mean())

    outcome.append(team_a_win_prob)
```

```
Season = []
ATeam = []
BTeam = []


for index, row in SampleSubmissionWarmup_df.iterrows():
    Season = SampleSubmissionWarmup_df.Season
    ATeam = SampleSubmissionWarmup_df.ATeam
    BTeam = SampleSubmissionWarmup_df.BTeam
    get_matchup(row['ATeam'],row['BTeam'],row['Season'])
```

This is why I think it loops through 427k rows before failing:

[Full Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cp79.png)

Feel free to critique my code too!  Total newb here.

Thanks!

I tried to run a for loop using a function I created so I can run my ML algorithm for each row in a given DF that lists out two teams and pits them against one another.

I expected it to add all the data to a series that I could add onto my existing DF to export the results.

Comment: Full error message please!

Comment: Sorry about that!  I should have mentioned that the full error message is in the image link

Comment: The error is in an array produced by a `load` function, so we can't help you.  I suspect some sort of slicing off the end of an array.

Comment: Thank you!  Just to be sure, are you referring to "loaded_model" as the load function?